# Id not being passed back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

The manageuser post back method is being called but the UserId is not being passed it comes back as 0. How do I correct this issue?

The html from view

```
<input type="image"
       src="~/icons/bootstrap-icons-1.10.2/bootstrap-icons.css"
       alt=""
       class="bi bi-check-circle-fill fs-6"
       name="btnDelete"
       aria-label="Delete user"
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ManageUser", "ManageUsers", new {@executeAction = "Delete", @userId = @item.UserID})'" />
```

The controller code

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ManageUser(string Status, string? StatusMessage)
{
    TempData["Message"] = "";
    if(statusMessage != null)
    {
        TempData["Message"] = statusMessage;
    }

    //load model
    return View(model)
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ManageUser(string executeAction, int userId)
{
    string status = action;
    string statusMessage = string.Empty;

    if(executeAction == "Delete")
    {
        //delete the user
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ManageUser", "ManageUsers", status, statusMessage);
}
```

Comment: can you also add some code how you are getting the userID? Is it model binded? Also just to make sure the uesrId is actually available on the page you can create a textbox input and bind to it, just for verification that its having the value.

Comment: The parms are being passed - <input type="image" src="/icons/bootstrap-icons-1.10.2/bootstrap-icons.css" alt="" class="bi bi-check-circle-fill fs-6" name="btnDelete" aria-label="Delete user" onclick="location.href='/ManageUsers/ManageUser?executeAction=Delete&amp;userId=2240'">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The manageuser post back method is being called but the UserId is not
> being passed it comes back as 0. How do I correct this issue?

Well, as you may know [Tag Helpers class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) generate link on page. Thus, we have either need to send request using query string or define get method on your controller action.

If you could seen in tag helper class service reference it doesn't allow httpverb by default because it takes request as URL that's query string.

[image]

**Solution:**

To resolve the issue either we have to define controller action as GET, just as following:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult ManageUser(string executeAction, int userId)
        {
            string status = "";
            string statusMessage = string.Empty;

            if (executeAction == "Delete")
            {
                //delete the user
            }

            return RedirectToAction("ManageUser", "ManageUsers", status, statusMessage);
        }
```

View:

```
<input type="button"
       src="~/icons/bootstrap-icons-1.10.2/bootstrap-icons.css"
       alt=""
       class="bi bi-check-circle-fill fs-6"
       name="btnDelete"
       value="Delete User"
       aria-label="Delete user"
     
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ManageUser", "Some", new {@executeAction = "Delete", @userId = "111"})'" />
```

**Note:** Everything would remain same as yours.

**Output:**

[image]

**Alternative Way:**

We can directly pass our parameter using [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href) what more is, it will send controller parameter as query string and will act accordingly.

**Note:** If you need more information about [ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/?view=aspnetcore-7.0), you can [have a look on official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)